# How to pass dynamic custom option id to the react-select option?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm facing the issue on the react-select package.
I'm going to pass the id to the every options in the Select component from the react-select component.

[image]

My code looks like bellow.

```
var options = [
   {id: 'lease', label: 'Lease', id: 'ownership-details-option-lease'},
   {id: 'own', label: 'own', id: 'ownership-details-option-own'}
]
```

I'm going to add the id to the option in the react-select component.

```
<Select
    name='ownershipstatus'
    onChange={(e) => {}
    ...
    }
    options={options}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'option' objects cannot have two `id` keys. Object keys must be unique, or the last defined will overwrite the first.

You have two props, `getOptionLabel: (option:Object) => String` and `getOptionValue: (option:Object) => String` that you use to define "this is the displayed value and this is the actual value".

pseudocode:

```js
  <Select
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.customLabel}
    getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
    value={someValueState}
    onChange={({target: {value}}) => setSomeValueState(value)}
    {...otherProps}
  />
```

The `value` you pass in to your control should equate to the 'value' of an option. Are you trying to set an explicit 'id' on options in your list? Why? Are you attempting to write unit testing? If so, use [react-select-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-event) and [@testing-library/react](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/). You won't need those id's. If it's something else, give us a valid use case.